# Import CSV File into Oracle using SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, csv, import, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to import data from a CSV file into a Oracle GroupSpace table using SQL Developer tool. I am getting errors for Date column. My Date column has Date in the below format.

```
5/6/2016
4/11/2018
11/6/2017...
```

I get error that the date column has Invalid or Null Date Formats.

Any pointers on what format date format to use when importing Date column would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much!
JH

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't sure that dates are valid (for example, nothing prevents you from entering `5/55/2016` into a CSV file, and that certainly isn't a valid DATE value), you can create a staging table whose columns are of VARCHAR2 datatype - it accepts *everything*, even garbage like 5/55/2016.

Then, after you load data, write some SQL to find errors, fix them, and then move data into the target table.

Answer (score 0):

Check the CSV data in a text editor and look for which part represents the month (the month value will be in the range 1..12). If you are using US dates then use `MM/DD/YYYY`, otherwise you should probably use `DD/MM/YYYY` as the date format. If the data has a mixture of both, then you must separate those files and use a different format for each, or you are likely to get invalid date values in your database.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Developer can help you.

[image]

You can try the date format masks in the drop-down. If we can guess it, we'll default to one. For some reason your data...fools us, but you can type your own.

If you get something that 'works' the warnings go away.

If you get it wrong, we'll let you know before you even get to the next step.

[image]

[You can find all the data format masks here.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212)

Comment: Great to hear, @JHegde